# Find out the Codec for a Quicktime Movie

Tags: cocoa, quicktime, codec

I´ve been wondering if it is possible to find out which Codec is used to Decompress a Quicktime Movie (like h.264, motion jpeg.. ), preferable as `NSString`. I searched through the `Quicktime` and `QTKit` api and all gettable attributes with no success, but I am sure there must be a way to do this, but how?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having this difficulty because you're misunderstanding the nature of a Quicktime movie - it doesn't make sense to ask what the codec of a movie is, and that's why you're not finding it in the documentation for movies.

Quicktime movies are made of a collection of **tracks** (eg. video track, audio track etc.) and each track references one or more **media** (the actual data). It's the media that is compressed with a particular codec. Usually a movie will have a video track and an audio track, for instance, each of which will be compressed with a different codec (h.264 and aac maybe) - so there isn't *one codec* for the whole movie.

To find the codec used to compress the video track of the movie (which sounds like what you're trying to do) you need to first get a reference to that track from the movie, then get a reference to the media of that track, then find out the codec used for that media. To get information about how the samples for a particular media object are stored you need to use the **getmediasampledescription** call.

If you're using QTKit, get the C-level media reference by calling [media quicktimeMedia] - then you can pass this to getmediasampledescription to get the info you're looking for - the codec 4-digit identifer is in the cType field of the returned sample description.

There's a bit of sample code in this apple support list posting :

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005//Aug/msg00556.html