# Getting a codecs OSType from a UTType format in pyobjc

Tags: objective-c, quicktime, codec, pyobjc, qtkit

I'm currently writing a script that processes batches of quicktimes, and its my first time using pyobjc (I have only written one other really simple script in actual objective-c). I need to be able to determine the four character OSType of the codec of the quicktimes so that I can properly use the same codec for images using addImage_forDuration_withAttributes_()

Because pyobjc only has access to the obj-c frameworks, I can't access any of the C functions from it. I am able to get the string format UTType of the codec:

```
from objc import YES, NO, nil
from Cocoa import *
from QTKit import *

movieAttribs = {
    QTMovieOpenAsyncOKAttribute: NSNumber.numberWithBool_(NO),
    QTMovieEditableAttribute: NSNumber.numberWithBool_(YES),
    QTMovieFileNameAttribute: "quicktime.mov"
}

clip, err = QTMovie.movieWithAttributes_error_(movieAttribs, None)
track = clip.tracks()[0]
print track.format()
# u'Avid DNxHD Codec'
```

At this point I need to get the OSType, which for this codec would be 'AVdn'
I'm assuming I want something like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html But I don't have access to it in pyobjc

My last resort is to shell out to [qt_thing](http://omino.com/sw/qt_tools/man/qt_thing.html) with something like this:

```
qt_thing --type=imco | grep "AVID DNxHD Codec" | awk -F: '{print $2}'
# Result: AVdn
```

But this is slower and I would rather do it all in code. I must be missing something that is available to me in the Cocoa/QTKit side of things. Anyone with any experience?

There is another SO question that again references using the C api to resolve the codec: [Find out the Codec for a Quicktime Movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842920/find-out-the-codec-for-a-quicktime-movie), but I can't obviously do that directly form pyobjc as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I waited for someone to answer, and kept digging, even into the Carbon module... I found that there are quite a number of methods wrapped into pyobjc objects that are not really documented in the docs or probably even present in the native QTKit objc. I figure this is to offset the lack of access to the Quicktime C-api layer.

First my search turned up this QTKit class: [QTFormatDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/quicktime/Reference/QTFormatDescription_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But there was no clear way how to create one of these. Apparently I wasn't the only one [confused as to how to retrive one](http://osdir.com/ml/quicktime-api/2010-06/msg00035.html)

When I started searching the actual members of QTMovie, QTTrack, and QTMedia objects, looking for possibly a way to retrieve a QTFormatDescription object, I stumbled across a method call:  `QTTrack.mediaSubType`

```
>>> movie = QTMovie.alloc().initWithFile_error_("/path/to/quicktime.mov", None)
>>> track = movie.tracks()[1]
>>> track.mediaSubType()
u'AVdn'
```

I guess they do wrap up a lot of convenience methods into the pyobjc instances so that you can retrieve this kind of information without the C-api. Its just a shame that its so undocumented.

For anyone looking for random functionality like this, all I can recommend is doing something like this to find any added non-arg methods that might be available to you:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([attrib for attrib in dir(QTTrack) if not '_' in attrib])
....
mediaName
mediaRetained
mediaSubType
mediaType
mediaTypeInMedia
...
```

Answer (score 0):

pyobjc does contain access to `UTType` it's under `LaunchServices`.

```
from LaunchServices import *

UTCreateStringForOSType()
UTGetOSTypeFromString()
```

Comment: I gave this a try, and the `OSType` returned is an integer id. Do you have an  example of how to get the 4 character type? For instance, if I run this example against an h.264 quicktime, I am looking to ultimately get `avc1`. Is there a way to translate the numeric id into the string?